# javascript form validate not preventing css .submitted from actioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a form with a class="myfrm" and contains a fieldset made up of input fields. After the fieldset tag I have a div tag and assigned class="ack-msg" which contains an acknowledgement message.

In CSS I have

```
.myfrm.submitted fieldset {
    display: none;
}
.myfrm.submitted .ack-msg {
    display: block;
}
```

When the form is submitted the fieldset is replaced by the acknowledgement.
This works fine when the form is completed as expected but when the form validation fails a message is displayed but the acknowldgement class="ack-msg" kicks in and replaces the fieldset as if it passed.

The validation is carried out by a javascript function called by the onSubmit on the form. The javascript is listed below and to keep things simple I have a shorted version of the script that only passes the validation if the provided parameter value = 24.

```
function validateForm(v) 
{
  if(v.value != '24')
  { 
    alert("Oops! Try agan!");
    return false;
  } else { 
    return true;
  }
}
```

Also, if I inspect the page after validation fails and acknowledgement gets diaplayed form declaration has been updated from 
    class="my-frm"
to 
    class="my-frm submitted"

If I should be listing other details please let me know.

Any help welcome on this.

Thanks in advance,
Ned

Comment: Would you mind creating a [runnable code snippet](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for us to see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the **submitted** class using javascript, right after the alert.
If you have jQuery:

```
function validateForm(v) 
{
    if(v.value != '24')
    { 
        alert("Oops! Try agan!");
        $.(".my-frm").removeClass("submitted");
        return false;
    } else { 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried that, I still get the same result.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @NedCooney what do you mean by same result? Is the class still there or has it been removed? If it's still there you probably have to remove it in a later event. Try debugging to check when the class is added and when it is removed, you may learn somehting interesting :)

Comment: Fabio, yes the submitted class is still there. I tried adding .passed and .failed classes for the message and ack classes for to distinguish  validation but it's messy. 
I think the best way is to implement in a different way. I'm working on it now and will post the final working answer but removing the submitted class doesn't resolve the issue.